# Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to inject the FortuneService interface to the TennisCoach class but I am getting the error and If I am trying to inject it using new keyword then it is working fine. I tried it by using creating the object of HappyFortuneService. I have tried like below in TennisCoach class
FortuneService fortuneService = new HappyFortuneService(); but if I am trying to inject it using constructor injection it is giving me below error.

I am getting the error like Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

```
package com.annotation;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.annotation.coach.Coach;
import com.annotation.coach.FortuneService;
import com.annotation.coach.HappyFortuneService;
import com.annotation.coach.TennisCoach;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication.class, args);

        Coach coach = new TennisCoach();
        logger.info(coach.getDailyWorkout());
        logger.info(coach.getDailyFortune());

    }

}




package com.annotation.coach;

public interface Coach {

    public String getDailyWorkout();
    public String getDailyFortune();
}




    package com.annotation.coach;

    import org.slf4j.Logger;
    import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    import com.annotation.Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication;

    @Component
    public class TennisCoach implements Coach {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication.class);

        private FortuneService fortuneService;

        public TennisCoach(FortuneService fortuneService) {
            this.fortuneService = fortuneService;
        }
        public TennisCoach() {
        }

        @Override
        public String getDailyWorkout() {
            return "*************Tennis Coach Daily Workout*************";
        }

        @Override
        public String getDailyFortune() {
            logger.info("*********INVOKED***************");
            return fortuneService.getFortune();
        }

    }




    package com.annotation.coach;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component
    public class HappyFortuneService implements FortuneService {

        @Override
        public String getFortune() {
            return "*************Happy Fortune Service*************";
        }

    }



package com.annotation.coach;

public interface FortuneService {

    public String getFortune();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create any bean using new keyword that bean will not added to Spring Application Context,so Coach coach = new TennisCoach(); not added to Application context. So class TennisCoach not recognizing the Autowired FortuneService.

you can do Autowired using Constructor, the instance of Coach is injected as an argument to the constructor when Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication is created.

Please find modified code below

@SpringBootApplication

public class Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication {

```
private static Coach coach;
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication.class);

@Autowired
public Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication(Coach coach) {
    Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication.coach = coach;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Luv2CodeAnnotationApplication.class, args);

  //Coach coach = new TennisCoach();
    logger.info(coach.getDailyWorkout());
    logger.info(coach.getDailyFortune());

}
```

}